# Automatic installation of .NET framework from InnoSetup installer

Tags: .net, inno-setup, setup-project

I'm using the following code to install the .NET package automatically

```pascal
procedure dotnetfx40full();
begin
    if (not netfxinstalled(NetFx40Full, '')) then
        AddProduct('dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe',
            CustomMessage('dotnetfx40full_lcid') + ' /q /passive /norestart',
            CustomMessage('dotnetfx40full_title'),
            CustomMessage('dotnetfx40full_size'),
            dotnetfx40full_url,
            false, false);
end;
```

It's using this project. Please check cannot post full code here.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-Installer-for-InnoSetup

But after the .NET installer is downloaded and the installer is executed with switches, the .NET installer does not work. It shows this message regarding proper usage of switches.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to execute `dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe /q /passive /norestart` manually, you get the same behavior.

After some testing, I believe you cannot combine `/q` and `/passive`. It makes sense as both do the same thing little differently.

Just use only one of the `/q` or the `/passive` in your code, depending 
if you want to see a progress (`/passive`) or not (`/q`).

Comment: @techno If the collected information does not help you, make sure you include what you have found into your question.

Comment: It was the issue with the space in the directive ' /q /passive /norestart' when i removed the space '/q/passive/norestart' it works but the license agreement for .net framwork is shown.I had used the same code (modified) to create my old installer,it runs fine and does not ask for MS license agreement.Unfortunately i lost that code,so im writing again.What's going wrong here?

Comment: Seems like `/q` cannot be combined with `/passive`. It actually does not make sense anyway, as both do the same thing, just differently. Just remove the `/passive` from your code.

Comment: I removed that,but now there is no progress window.I need to show the user progress as its a long process.

Comment: Well that's what `/q` does. If you want progress, use `/passive` instead.

Comment: Thanks,that fixed it.I did not doubt the directive since the project used it and i had used the project previously.May be the project was updated.